# Applying discount to Javascript cart

Tags: javascript, cart

I am trying to have a discount applied to this file/shopping cart.  I am able to get the discount function working but it continuously removes the total instead of only once.  Any suggestions?

```
function totalCost(product, action) {
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
    
    console.log("My cartCost is", cartCost);
    console.log(typeof cartCost );
    if(action == "decrease") {
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
        localStorage.setItem('totalCost',cartCost - product.price);
    } else if(cartCost != null) {
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + product.price);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.price);
    }
}

function discountCart() {
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

    // VARIABLES FOR 20 OR 50
    var discount20 = parseInt(cartCost) - 20
    var discount50 = parseInt(cartCost) - 50
    
    console.log("My cartCost is", cartCost);
    console.log(typeof cartCost );

    // DISCOUNT FUNCTIONALITY
    if (cartCost >= 50 || cartCost <= 75) {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost = discount20)
        console.log('discount 20!', cartCost = discount20)
    } else if (cartCost >= 200 || cartCost <= 250){
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost = discount50)
        console.log('discount 50!', cartCost = discount50)
    };
}
```

Comment: How do you call the `discountCart()` function? What do you mean by "continuously"?

Comment: I tried calling it at the end of the file but this creates an error since there is nothing in the cart.  When I call it at the same times I call the totalCost() function it is called as well so it fires multiple times.

Comment: I am not sure if I should be placing the discount logic in a function or keep it as it's own function

Answer (score 0):

At:

```
// VARIABLES FOR 20 OR 50
var discount20 = parseInt(cartCost) - 20
var discount50 = parseInt(cartCost) - 50
```

Instead of using the `-` operator use the `-=` instead, like so:

```
// VARIABLES FOR 20 OR 50
var discount20 = parseInt(cartCost) -= 20
var discount50 = parseInt(cartCost) -= 50
```

Also, at:

```
localStorage.setItem('totalCost',cartCost - product.price);
```

Do the same:

```
localStorage.setItem('totalCost',cartCost -= product.price);
```

Likewise replace every `+` operator with `+=` in your code.

Also, carefully read:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

to understand javascript operators.

Comment: This is not correct BTW., It would produce an error `SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression.`

Comment: `let discount20 = parseInt(cost) -= 20;` is same as `let discount20 = parseInt(cost) = parseInt(cost) - 20;`

Comment: @HR01M8055 Really? In that case It should be `=-`?

Comment: @HR01M8055 Nope, both aren't the same. Try the code yourself.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question I had, the math is correct...

Comment: @AmySmith In that case I fail to understand what exactly the question is, can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan I want the function/discount to only be applied once.  However, it is applied every time someone adds an item to the cart if the cart is over 50